# Remapping HTTP requests fields to another service

Tags: php, remap

Essentially what i'm looking for is a solution that will parse fields (from GET and POST requests) and remap them to another service (URL)

For example, this might be the workflow:

1. User submits form with three fields: 'myname','myemail' and
   'myphone'. the request is sent over to the system on a url: 
   `http://www.remap-system.com/redirect-to-service1/`
2. The system parses the form and remaps the preconfigured fields :

   myname => name,
   myemail => email,
   myphone => phone
3. The system sends the new remapped requests to service1 url (with
   POST or GET)

On WordPress we've got a plugin that does just that, but I'm looking for a system that is more robust and autonomical.
Is there a ready made system for that?
If not, what will be the easiest way to implement that?

Comment: This is a fairly trivial thing to create - where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not stuck, I'm looking for a ready made solution that will let me add service URLs and their corresponding mappings.
an API solution if you rather.

Answer (score 1):

Coffee-break answer :)

```
$map = [ "myname" => "name" ];
$src = $_POST;
$dst = [];
foreach($src as $k=>$v) {
  if(isset($map[$k]) {
    $dst[$map[$k]] = $v;
  }
}

// var_dump($dst);
// send $dst somewhere
```

Comment: +1 but I'd rather loop through the mapping and check if `src` isset

Comment: Thanks, yes and more improvement can be done (eg make recursive, handle GET/POST automatically). Mine was mostly an initial idea

Comment: Thanks Muka, That's what I used until now, but i'm looking for a solution that will let me also add/remove and manage the service URL and mappings easily, without dealing with code.
Wondering if there's a ready made solution (a ping post service is probably an overkill for that...)